# Como chamar outra pagina PHP dentro de uma pagina PHP

Tags: php

Galera,

Tenho uma pagina PHP e agora preciso chamar uma outra página PHP passando os parâmetros que coletei do meu BD.

Como posso fazer isso?

Já tentei assim, mas não foi!

```
$qry_str = "id=".$id_mensagem;
$ch      = curl_init();

// Set query data here with the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '/postar_reenvio.php?' . $qry_str);
//$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$strSearch."&hl=en&start=0&sa=N";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
print_r($content);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Que vc já tentou fazer?

Comment: $qry_str = "id=".$id_mensagem;
$ch      = curl_init();

// Set query data here with the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'postar_reenvio.php?' . $qry_str);
//$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=".$strSearch."&hl=en&start=0&sa=N";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
print_r($content);
curl_close($ch);

Comment: Qual erro ocorre?

Comment: ja pensou em usar include 'postar_reenvio.php' e utilizar os métodos do reenvio na página atual?

Comment: não posso usar include pois essa chamada vai ficar em um loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu bem percebi a sua questão está deverá ser a sua solução

```
   // Obter os recursos de cURL 
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://testcURL.com/?item1=value&item2=value2'
    ));
    // enviar o request  & guarda a resposta em $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    // fechar o request
    curl_close($curl);
```